# How to connect to the internet, via a bluetooth access point, from command line

Tags: debian, bluetooth, arm, access-point, iot

The question may seem highly specific, but I didn't seem any answer anywhere.

Accessing the internet via a bluetooth access point sounds like an odd choice, but I believe it's the right one in my case, where a very small machine with a small battery running debian, should be able to connect to the internet every time once in a while at a low battery cost.

I have, at my disposal, android and ios devices that are able to share an internet connection via bluetooth.

My own device has a micro controller that also has a bluetooth chip.
It can normally scan devices, pair to them, and connect to them via bluetooth (done using bluetoothctl), but I couldn't find how to establish an internet connection via a BT device I am connected to.

In fact I don't even know how to test it: can I just leave the bluetoothctl prompt and ping google? Is that even a thing that can be done, provided an internet connection was established?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/254794/how-can-i-share-my-internet-connection-via-bluetooth

Answer (score 2):

You could use **nmcli**

```
# to list available connections
nmcli connection show

# to connect to abcd
nmcli connection up "abcd"
```